# Image disappears when mouse clicked and T F updating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having two issues. The image I want to move disappears and the status of the mouse click is not updating.

I'm trying to have an image move with the mouse and record the mouse location.  When I click I want the image to stop following the mouse. The souse location will stop counting and the mouse image is following mouse will display false.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var init = true;
  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $(this)[init ? 'on' : 'off']('mousemove', follow);
    init = !init;
  });

  function follow(e) {
    var xPos = e.pageX;
    var yPos = e.pageY;
    $("#gallery").html("The image is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos);
    $("#clickstatus").html("Image is following mouse T/F" + ": " + !init);
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
      $("#moveimage").mousemove({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>IT 411</h1>
<h2>Displaying a gallery of images</h2>
<hr />
<p>Click anywhere on this page to make the image move using mousemove</P>
<p id="clickstatus"></p>
</div>

<div id="gallery">
  <img id="moveimage" class="image" src="images/gnu.jpg" height="200px" width="250px" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The image disappears because you overwrite it with `$("#gallery").html("The image is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos);`. You need to write coordinates to some other element.
2. The status of the mouse click is not updating for two reasons: (1) when you pass the `follow` function to the `click` handler you pluck from its original scope so it does not see `init` anymore, (2) you unsubscribe from the `mousemove` event so the function does not run anymore. So you need to move `$("#clickstatus").html("Image is following mouse T/F" + ": " + !init);` to the `click` handler.
3. To change the coordinates of the image you need to use jQuery's `css` function. Also the wrapping `$(document).mousemove(function(e) {` is not needed.
4. For `left` and `top` properties to have any effect the element should have `position` to be set to `fixed` or `absolute`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var init = true;
  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $(this)[init ? 'on' : 'off']('mousemove', follow);
    init = !init;
    // 2.
    $("#clickstatus").html("Image is following mouse T/F" + ": " + !init);
  });

  function follow(e) {
    var xPos = e.pageX;
    var yPos = e.pageY;
    $("#coordinates").html("The image is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos);
    // 3.
    $("#moveimage").css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#moveimage{
  position: fixed; /* 4. */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>IT 411</h1>
<h2>Displaying a gallery of images</h2>
<hr />
<p>Click anywhere on this page to make the image move using mousemove</P>
<p id="clickstatus"></p>
</div>

<div id="gallery">
  <img id="moveimage" class="image" src="images/gnu.jpg" height="200px" width="250px" />
</div>
<!-- 1. -->
<div id="coordinates"></div>
```